# How can i make a function that finds an object in a set?

Tags: c++

I'm making a program that generates a maze and then uses bredth first search to find a way in the maze. My function that checks if an element is present in a container-class now uses the vector like this (where coordinatePath is a typedef for vector) :

```
bool Labyrinth::inVisited(const Coordinate &c, const coordinatePath &visited ) const
{
    for each (Coordinate coord in visited)
    {
        if(coord == c)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Since this method has to traverse the full container if an element is not present it's very ineffective for large searches. I tried to implement the same function that uses a set instead of a vector and wrote it like this:

```
bool Labyrinth::inVisited(const Coordinate &c, const set<Coordinate> &visited ) const
{
       return (visited.find(c) != visited.end());
}
```

when i try to recomplie i get a lot of errors where the topmost is

Error   22  error C2676: binary '<' : 'const Coordinate' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstddef  193

I don't really understand these particular debug-messages and wonder if there is a way to implement this faster search!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use elements in a `set` the `value_type` has to define `operator<` or you need to provide a comparison functor to the container. Apparently, your `Coordinate` type doesn't do that or the `operator<` you provide takes incompatible arguments. It should look roughly like this:

```
struct Coordinate {
  bool operator<(const Coordinate& other) const { return false; }
};

// or by providing a functor
struct CmpCoord {
  bool operator()(const Coordinate& x, const Coordinate& y);
}; 
typedef std::set<Coordinate, CmpCoord> coord_set;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response!

Comment: @pmr: `Coordinate(0,0) < Coordinate(0,0)` was `true`, which violated the Strict Weak Ordering requirement. In general, all coordinates were unequal even to themselves. I changed it so all coordinates are equal, which is valid.

Comment: @MSalters Thanks. I was just banging out syntax without considering semantics as there was no clue what `Coordinate` actually was.

Answer (score 2):

In order to create a `std::set` of objects, those objects have to define `operator <`.

So you need to add the following operator:

```
inline bool operator < (const Coordinate& first, const Coordinate& other);
```

Comment: Good answer. But it might be good to say that not only `operator<()` must be defined but also that it must be implemented with consistency and provide **strict weak ordering**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response!